# Why do app crashes after update from play market, but after reinstall works?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

After updating from Play Market, the application does not start (it starts and immediately crashes). However, if the app is completely uninstalled and reinstalled from the Play Market, it works fine.

in the last version we bumped `minSdkVersion` from `16` to `21`.

build.gradle:

```
buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 21 /*was 16*/
compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 29
```

Numerous crash reports:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
  at okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.decodeHeaderAsJavaNetCookies (JavaNetCookieJar.java:91)
  at okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.loadForRequest (JavaNetCookieJar.java:74)
  at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ReactCookieJarContainer.loadForRequest (ReactCookieJarContainer.java:44)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.kt:75)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
  at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain (RealCall.kt:194)
  at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run (RealCall.kt:138)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

What did we do wrong? Why does the application work fine after reinstalling?

Comment: Hello @pedroGarciyaLopez! Any news on this issue? It seems I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Hi @LenoirZamboni! In our case the problem was in difference of okhttp versions. Module A was dependent on one version and module B was dependent on another version. During the update of the app from the store, the old version of the OKHTTP somehow remained. Then module B tried to call a non-existent method from old OKHTTP. This was the cause of the crashes. After synchronizing of OKHTTP versions problem was solved.